# How to use variadic templates to wrap a variable number of function arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I want to take a variable number of function arguments, and in the function itself, wrap each function argument using a template wrapper class and pass these wrapper classes as arguments to another function.

Say if I have a template class that simply wraps a variable.

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T t) : t_(t)
.
.
    {}
private:
    T t_;
}
```

And I have a function *f* that calls function *g*, passing in Wrapper classes for each argument of *f* to *g*.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void f(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c)
{
    g(Wrapper<T1>(a), Wrapper<T2>(b), Wrapper<T3>(c));
}
```

Function *g* is not important here, but could be for example, a sequence of overloaded functions, each with a different number and type of *Wrapper* classes as its parameters.

Is there a way to use variadic templates to call template method *f* with a variable number of arguments, passing in the same number of arguments but instead with their wrapper classes into function *g*?

Any help much appreciated,
Tony

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://ideone.com/rc8rqc) ? Not sure I understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical term is [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

And it should as "easy" as

```
template<typename... T>
void f(T... args)
{
    g(Wrapper<T>(args)...);
}
```

Of course, it requires you to have the proper `g` function.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise also how flexible parameter packs are. For example replacing the call to function g with this:

    g(&Wrapper<T>(*args)...);


allows for pointers as arguments to function f, to be dereferenced to form Wrapper classes. Then the pointer for each Wrapper class is passed on to g instead.